# Does 2 Single core = 1 Dual Core?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores

Recently I attempted to suggest to a group that we should have our hardware upgraded on one of our rendering servers. The server has 2 single core CPUs, and I suggested that we really should have more than single core CPUs to increase our rendering speeds.

However, somebody replied and said "Two single core CPUs = 1 Dual Core CPU, so this point is largely moot"

What? Is that accurate, for servers and such? I've done some searching and haven't been able to find a sufficient answer to this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Accurate enough in the big picture sense.  Two single cores should be about equivalent to a dual-core (note dual-core, and not a single hyperthreaded core).  You should really benchmark the server and find out where the bottleneck is - it might be that disk or memory are limiting more than CPU.

Comment: You won't find an answer without benchmarking your specific load. In general, having 2 CPUs, or cores is the major and probably only benefit, so they would be "equal".  Depending on the case (software load and system architectures) though, the tight integration of a dual core may help performance, and in other cases having two separated CPUs (and all accompanying parts) may be what's beneficial. Having said that, hex-cores+ are easily available these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's accurate. A dual-core CPU is, more or less, the same as two single-core CPUs in one package.

However, it's quite likely that these single-core CPUs are much, much slower than modern CPUs. Even with two of them, they're still likely to be quite a bit slower than a modern, multi-core CPU.

Comment: It looks like the most recent single core Xeon (Irwindale) used 90nm (compared to current 22nm) manufacturing process *and* was based on Netburst, so "much, much slower" would be very true. With proper software support for the most recent SIMD extensions, vectorizable FP workloads ("rendering" would probably fit in this category) would do especially well.